# No results with sql query

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently trying to build an instant search function for a website but have ran in to trouble with a sql query.

I'm trying to select names from a database that contains the letters that have been entered in a textbox.

This is my query:

```
mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT name FROM drinks LIKE '%$partialSearch%'");
```

Nothing gets returned even though I got values in the table that contains the letter/letters. Everything works fine when not using the LIKE keyword. So what is going on?

Comment: `... WHERE some_field LIKE ...`. Checking the return value and error message would have shown you exactly where the problem was

Comment: Thanks a lot Phil! I forgot the WHERE keyword. Still learning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"SELECT name FROM drinks where yourField LIKE '%$partialSearch%'"
```